# Minecraft mod proxy

Tags: overriding, minecraft-forge

Hi I'm doing a minecraft mod and I have a CommonProxy and ClientProxy my ClientProxy extends CommonProxy and in my common proxy I have a public static void registerRenders and in my ClientProxy an @Override public static void registerRenders etc.. my IDE underline the Override and print "Method does not override method from its superclass"

Answer (score 1):

static methods cannot be overridden. Make both of them instance methods and it will work.